# Access: How to execute a query and save its result in a report

Tags: ms-access

HI,

I am trying to write a query in vba and to save its result in a report.
I am a beginner. this is what i have tried 
can somebody correct me

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
sql = "Select * from table1 where empno is 0"

rs.Open sql, cn


While Not rs.EOF

' here i think i should save the result in a report but i am not sure how

  rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Also how do i change this query to run this on all tables in a database

Comment: What do you mean by report? Do you mean as HTML or word document?

Answer (score 1):

**IF you are wanting to create a report using MS Access's report generator**, you will have to use a Query Object (there might be a way to trick MS Access into running it off of your record set, but it's probably not worth your effort).

You can create the Query Object on the "Database" window. Click the Query button in the objects list, and then click on New. In the resulting editor you can create the query graphically or if you prefer with SQL. Save the query and give it a meaning full name.

Similarly the report can be created on the "Database" window. Click on the Report button and then on New. In the resulting wizard, you'll link the report to the query you just created.
***Update:*** As D.W. Fenton said, you can embed the query right within the Report Object without creating a separate Query Object. My preference is to create one anyway.

The problem with this method is you would have to create a separate query and report for each table.

**IF you just want to dump the result out to a text file (to read/print later)**, then you can do it using recordsets like you are in your VBA code. It will look something like this

```
'...
dim strFoo as string
dim strBar as string
'...
if not rs.bof then
    rd.MoveFirst
end if
While Not rs.EOF
   strFoo = rs("foo") 'copy the value in the field 
                      'named "foo" into strFoo.
   strBar = rs("bar")
   '... etc. for all fields you want
   '
   'write out the values to a text file 
   '(I'll leave this an exercise for the reader)
   '
   rs.MoveNext
Wend
'...
```

Parsing all of the tables can be done in a loop something like this:

```
dim strTableName as string
dim db As Database
'...
Set db = CurrentDb
db.TableDefs.Refresh
For Each myTable In db.TableDefs
    If Len(myTable.Connect) > 0 Then
        strTableName = myTable.Name
        '...
        'Do something with the table
        '...
    End If
Next
set db = nothing
```

**=======================UPDATE=======================**
**It is possible to run an MS-Access Report from a record set.** To repease what I said to [tksy's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242504/accesshow-can-i-generate-a-report-of-a-recordset)
From [Access Web](http://www.mvps.org/access/reports/rpt0014.htm) you can use the "name" property of a recordset. You resulting code would look something like this:

*In the report*

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.RecordSource = gMyRecordSet.Name
End Sub
```

*In the calling object (module, form, etc.)*

```
Public gMyRecordSet As Recordset
'...
Public Sub callMyReport()
    '...
    Set gMyRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * " & _
                                               "from foo " & _
                                               "where bar='yaddah'")
    DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview  
    '...
    gMyRecordSet.Close  
    Set gMyRecordSet = Nothing
    '...
End Sub
```

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: You don't need to save a query in order to run a report. The report definition has a Recordsource property that is stored with the report.

Comment: You don't need to create the recordset before you open the report. Just assign the SQL string you're using in OpenRecordset as the Recordsource property. And I don't think your code as written will work because you're assigning the *name* of a recordset opened in code to the Recordsource property.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would design the report based on a data source. Then after your report is done and working properly you use VBA to display or save the report.

Answer (score 0):

To run this for each table in the database, I'd suggest writing a function that looped through CurrentData.AllTables(i) and then called your function above in each iteration

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply view the results, you can create a query. For example, here is some rough, mostly untested VBA:

```
Sub ViewMySQL
Dim strSQL as String
Dim strName As String

'Note that this is not sensible in that you
'will end up with as many queries open as there are tables

    For Each tdf In CurrentDB.TableDefs
       If Left(tdf.Name,4)<>"Msys" Then
          strName = "tmp" & tdf.Name

          strSQL = "Select * from [" & tdf.Name & "] where empno = 0"
          UpdateQuery strName, strSQL
          DoCmd.OpenQuery strName, acViewNormal
       End If
    Next
End Sub

Function UpdateQuery(QueryName, SQL)

    If IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MsysObjects", "Name='" & QueryName & "'")) Then
        CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef QueryName, SQL
    Else
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).SQL = SQL
    End If

    UpdateQuery = True

End Function
```

You may also be interested in MDB Doc, an add-in for Microsoft Access 97-2003 that allows you to document objects/properties within an Access database to an HTML file.

-- http://mdbdoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do. If you want to view the results of SQL statement, you'd create a form and set its recordsource to "Select * from table1 where empno is 0". Then you could view the results one record at a time.

If that's not what you want, then I'm afraid I just don't have enough information to answer your question.

From what you *have* said so far, I don't see any reason why you need VBA or a report, since you just want to view the data. A report is for printing, a form is for viewing and editing. A report is page-oriented and not that easy to navigate, while a form is record-oriented, and allows you to edit the data (if you want to).

More information about what you want to accomplish will help us give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. just use the clipboard!

1. select the query results by click/dragging over all field names shown
2. press ctrl-c to copy to windows clipboard
3. open a blank document in word and click inside it
4. press ctrl-v to paste from clipboard.