# Set Access report's recordsource to ADODB recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a case where I want to set the Access reports recordset to the recordsets returned by query using an ADODB connection.

So In a report I cannot do something like:

```
Me.recordsource = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
```

because `TABLE1` does not exist in the database. Is there a way to do this without creating linked tables?

Comment: I tested with Access files. I was able to set Recordset property of a form but I have doubts can be done with report. It is possible to pull data from an Access file with report RecordSource property without setting link or connection, example: `SELECT * FROM tableORquery IN 'Z:\path\accessfile.accdb'`.

Comment: I tested ADO and DAO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242504/accesshow-can-i-generate-a-report-of-a-recordset) using Access files - both fail for report.

Comment: What kind of db are you connecting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the report recordset, but only if you're using an ADP:

```
Set Me.Recordset = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table1")
```

If you want to use an external table, you can use a passthrough query:

```
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("TempQuery")
qd.Connect = "ODBC;My ODBC connection string"
qd.SQL = "My SQL query"
Set qd = Nothing
Me.Recordsource = "SELECT * FROM TempQuery"
```

There are some tricks to permanently hide the passthrough query, and/or delete it once the report closes, but generally I like to keep them available for users to work with.